# Why does bootstrap gives different p-values for CC and my regression coefficient in simple linear regression?

Tags: r, regression, p-value

I'm using R and the package boot.

my boot function returns the coefficients and the r.square and sqrt of the r.square

```
 rsq2 <- function(formula, data, indices) {
     d <- data[indices,] # allows boot to select sample 
     fit <- lm(formula, data=d)
     return(c( coef(fit),summary(fit)$r.square,sqrt(summary(fit)$r.square)))
 }

boot(data=mtcars,rsq2,1000,formula="mpg~wt")

#ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP

Call:
boot(data = mtcars, statistic = rsq2, R = 1000, formula = "mpg~wt")


Bootstrap Statistics :
      original        bias    std. error
t1* 37.2851262  0.1170681005  2.32470420
t2* -5.3444716 -0.0557873180  0.70523904
t3*  0.7528328  0.0019940314  0.05758118
t4*  0.8676594  0.0004980607  0.03362469
```

I determine a pvalue using the original value and the std. error determined by the boot program

```
pvalue of the regression coefficient
2*pnorm(-abs(-5.3444716/0.70523904))
[1] 3.502706e-14
pvalue of the CC
 2*pnorm(-abs(0.8676594/0.03362469))
[1] 7.947938e-147
```

Why are these not the same value?

In a simple univariable the linear regression of the p-value of the coefficient and Pearson's CC are the same value?

Comment: What's "CC"? Do you mean 'correlation coefficient'?

Answer (score 1):

`t2*` is the bootstrapped slope (compare with `coef(lm(mpg~wt, mtcars))`). You are comparing apples with pears.

Furthermore, I don't think you are using the correct test. The test statistics for the correlation coefficient usually is $t = \frac{r\sqrt{n-2}}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}$. Also $\sqrt{r^2} \neq r$.

$r$ and $r^2$  are really not normal distributed, since they are limited to $[-1, 1]$ and $[0, 1]$. So, you can't simply use a z-test. For illustration, let's look at the bootstrapped distribution of $r^2$:

```
set.seed(42)
b <- boot(data=mtcars,rsq2,1000,formula="mpg~wt")
plot(density(b$t[,3]))
```

[image]

This would look even more extreme if $r^2$ was close to 0 or 1.

Normally, you can use the bootstrap confidence interval to judge significance:

```
quantile(b$t[,3], c(0.025, 0.975))
#     2.5%     97.5% 
#0.6320627 0.8646037
```

However, be aware that the lower confidence limit of $r^2$ can't be smaller than zero and it is usually extremely unlikely that zero is in the confidence interval.